# Shuffle dictionaries of sets in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, random, set, shuffle

I am trying to shuffle dictionaries of sets.
This is the set which I want to shuffle randomly

```
{'1': ['IMG_0001.png', 'IMG_0002.png', 'IMG_0003.png', 'IMG_0004.png'], 
 '2': ['IMG_0020.png', 'IMG_0021.png', 'IMG_0022.png', 'IMG_0023.png'], 
 '3': ['IMG_0051.png', 'IMG_0052.png', 'IMG_0053.png', 'IMG_0054.png']}
```

Output should be somewhat like this below

```
{'1': ['IMG_0001.png', 'IMG_0002.png', 'IMG_0053.png', 'IMG_0054.png'], 
 '2': ['IMG_0020.png', 'IMG_0021.png', 'IMG_0022.png', 'IMG_0023.png'], 
 '3': ['IMG_0003.png', 'IMG_0004.png', 'IMG_0051.png', 'IMG_0052.png']}
```

Tried using random.shuffle() in python but not getting as expected. Can anyone help me. I am a new beginner in python. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Those are lists, not sets.

Comment: Concatenate all the lists, and shuffle that list. Then split it up and put each sublist into a different dictionary element.

Comment: What did you call `random.shuffle()` on? You want to mix elements between different lists, it just shuffles the order of a single list.

Comment: @MarkMeyer You can see from the example that items move between different lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each list should have the same size and you want to shuffle all the elements of the lists among each other, you could use the following function:

```py
import random
import itertools


def shuffle(original: dict) -> dict:
    all_elements = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(original.values()))
    m = len(all_elements) // len(original)  # list size
    random.shuffle(all_elements)
    return {k: all_elements[i*m : (i+1)*m] for i, k in enumerate(original)}
```

Or, with the [`more-itertools`](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/) package:

```py
import random
import itertools
import more_itertools


def shuffle(original: dict) -> dict:
    all_elements = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(original.values()))
    list_length = len(all_elements) // len(original)
    random.shuffle(all_elements)
    return {k: l for k, l in more_itertools.sliced(all_elements, n=list_length)}
```

Sample usage:

```py
d = {
    "1": ["IMG_0001.png", "IMG_0002.png", "IMG_0003.png", "IMG_0004.png"],
    "2": ["IMG_0020.png", "IMG_0021.png", "IMG_0022.png", "IMG_0023.png"],
    "3": ["IMG_0051.png", "IMG_0052.png", "IMG_0053.png", "IMG_0054.png"],
}
print(shuffle(d))
```

```
{'1': ['IMG_0023.png', 'IMG_0003.png', 'IMG_0021.png', 'IMG_0001.png'],
 '2': ['IMG_0053.png', 'IMG_0051.png', 'IMG_0052.png', 'IMG_0004.png'],
 '3': ['IMG_0054.png', 'IMG_0022.png', 'IMG_0002.png', 'IMG_0020.png']}
```